# Plot a derivate function and the tangent to a plot

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis

Being f(x)= f(x) =  - x^2 + 4x - 3          if   x <  3 
            f(x)  =  3 -  x | x - 4 |           if   x >=  3
and with  h (x) = (x - 4) f(x). I have to prove that the derivate of h exists in x = 4. Then plot the function h and the tangent to the plot in x=4 in the same plot.

Comment: Sounds like homework ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
f[x_] = Piecewise[{{-x^2 + 4 x - 3, x < 3}}, 3 - x*Abs[x - 4]];

h[x_] = (x - 4) f[x];
```

At `x == 4` the derivative of `h[x]` exists in the limit

```
Limit[h'[x], x -> 4]

(* 3 *)
```

So the equation of the tangent passing through `{4, h[4]}` is `3 (x - 4) + h[4]`

```
Plot[{h[x], 3 (x - 4) + h[4]}, {x, 0.8, 5},
 PlotRange -> {-3, 3},
 Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Medium], Point[{4, h[4]}]},
 PlotLegends -> Placed[{"h[x]", "tangent at {4, h[4]}"}, {.5, .75}]]
```

[image]